# New to Ubuntu running 16.01 Drive issues Need help formating?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have a desktop that has 3 drives, I installed Ubuntu on the first drive. The other 2 drives I have formatted a couple of times. The only way I could get access to create files and folders was to format them NTFS.

It looks like the OS see's them as external drives. My question is should I have formatted them something differant? If so what and how?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on how to install Ubuntu ?

Comment: @George I'm sure the OP followed the instructions for the install.  His message indicating that he is using it, and now trying to learn how to use his other two drives for files and folders.  Of course, I could be misunderstanding his message if he's saying something different.

Comment: Dadmancpu1, I'm wondering what gives you the impression that Ubuntu is seeing your other two drives as external?  When I have actual external drives attached, I don't notice an indication in my OS that is specifying them as external.